# When does getPrivateKey get called in X509KeyManager?

Tags: java, ssl, communication, mutual-authentication

I'm writing my own implementation of X509KeyManager and I came across the function getPrivateKey(String alias){} and I'm just wondering when is that function gets called. In the documentation it is not very clear when and where all those functions are called. It's hard for me to understand the mechanics and execution flow of this. Can somebody help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, every time someone needs to sign or decrypt something, it will involve the PrivateKey. In the context of TLS/SSL, this will happen when you use client-based authentication.

Comment: Or if you're a server.